# Bind C-z in evil mode to escape to shell

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

In Emacs evil mode, the key combo `C-z` is to toggle evil mode. I would like to rebind it to escape to shell instead. How would I do this ?

I have read about eshell, it seems to be great, but for now I would like to work with my zsh shell first.

Multi term seems to designed for this job, but I think escaping to shell is fine for me, since I'm used to this flow in Vim.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps what you need is C-x C-z.

Answer (score 3):

Just have the same requirement, and here's my configurations:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/evil")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/evil/lib")
(setq evil-toggle-key ""); remove default evil-toggle-key C-z, manually setup later
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)

;; remove all keybindings from insert-state keymap, use emacs-state when editing
(setcdr evil-insert-state-map nil)

;; ESC to switch back normal-state
(define-key evil-insert-state-map [escape] 'evil-normal-state)
```

Ref:
 1. https://gist.github.com/kidd/1828878
 2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/99160/how-to-remap-emacs-evil-mode-toggle-key-from-ctrl-z

Answer (score 0):

`C-x C-z` will suspend the frame and return you to the shell.

`C-z` as you mention toggles evil mode on/off.

I swap their behavior in evil like so:

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "C-z") 'suspend-frame)
(define-key evil-emacs-state-map (kbd "C-z") 'suspend-frame)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "C-x C-z") 'evil-emacs-state)
(define-key evil-emacs-state-map (kbd "C-x C-z") 'evil-exit-emacs-state)
```

See [this commit](https://github.com/bschiela/dotrc/commit/00cef9d45ca147b225dc8ddd170c2f6d0ab62031) for an example (where I also make `C-z` emulate vim-behavior in insert/replace mode).